# Wireless mouse is not working

Tags: wireless, 13.10, mouse, dell

I have a Gigabyte wireless mouse (m7600), and Ubuntu 13.10 freshly installed on a Dell Inspiron n5110. My mouse isn't responding. The system recognizes the receiver. It shows up as Cypress Corp. if I run `lsusb`.

Things I have tried so far:

- Trying it on Windows 8.1 has no effect.
- Trying it on live distributions has no effect.
- Trying it in each USB port has no effect.
- Trying it on another computer is working.
- Trying other USB mice on this computer is working.
- Changing batteries has no effect.

It worked for quite some time, and suddenly stopped working yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, got it working now. The USB dongle was at fault, it's somehow a tiny bit damaged, enough so it won't connect the pins to the USB of my laptop, but still reach those on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out that my rechargeable AA battery had somehow stopped accepting a charge. When I put in another battery it fixed the problem. I switched from a Energizer to a Lenmar.

[image]

Comment: we all know what a AA battery is, we don't need a battery picture

Comment: @mustafa That's not just any AA battery. That's an energizer rechargeable battery. Please re-read my answer and don't be so critical. We're all volunteer contributors here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

1. Unplug dongle.
2. Run modprobe -r usbhid on the command line.
3. Plug dongle again.

Basically we are re installing the required drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. What's suspicious, that it doesn't work on windows either, but it does so on other machines.